# Javascript bookmarklet generates "SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical" error

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am stumped as to why this simple Javascript bookmarklet fails.

```
javascript:(setInterval(function() { 
     var element = document.getElementById("observeBtn");
      if (element != null) element.click(); 
}, 1000);)();
```

The error on the browser console is:

> SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical

I've counted the parentheses, and they all match (7 left, 7 right).

All this function is supposed to do is check every second for whether the `observeBtn` button exists on the web page, and if so, automatically press it.

Also, could someone explain what the last `"();"` is for?

Comment: `);)();` -> `))();`, i think...

Comment: Try `javascript:void setInterval(function() { var element = document.getElementById('observeBtn'); if (element != null) element.click(); }, 1000);`

Comment: Thanks, Ivar, that works!  If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
setInterval(function() { 
    var element = document.getElementById("observeBtn"); 
    if (element != null) element.click(); 
}, 1000);
```

Edit due to your edit - you don't need the last `()` that you had.

Comment: Can you at least tell me what "SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical" means?

Comment: You were trying to set the function up as an IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression), but it was the incorrect syntax to do so which is why it was yelling at you telling you that you were missing a ')'.

Comment: If you need to protect the scope of the function and the variables in it, then use a IIFE for this setInterval, but I am not sure the what the context for this code is.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to define an IIFE function you need to use its correct sintax:

```
(function(){
    // code here
})();
```

or ES6 arrow functions

```
(() => {
    // code here
})
```

So your IIFE function should looks like:

```
(function () {
    setInterval(function() { 

        var element = document.getElementById("observeBtn");
        if (element != null) element.click(); 

    }, 1000);
})();
```

Note an important aspect of the above code, you define a function and then call it with the last () parenthesis.

Comment: How should that look with the "javascript:" prefix?  I tried this:

```javascript:(function () {return setInterval(function() { var element = document.getElementById("observeBtn"); if (element != null) element.click(); }, 1000); })();``` but all it did was erase my page and replace it with the number 4208.

Comment: What is the final output you are looking for?

Comment: Remove the `return`.